# 'Debug-iphoneos/AmplifyRTNCore/AmplifyRTNCore.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, react-native, aws-amplify, apple-m1, xcode15

I am getting above error with following configuration:

- Mackbook Pro [Apple M1 Pro] [Sonoma 14.1]
- Xcode 15.2
- Device iPhone 15 Pro [17.3.1]
- react [18.2.0]
- react-native [0.73.4]
- aws-amplify [6.0.17]
- npm [10.5.0]
- node [21.7.1]
- gem [3.5.6]
- bundler [2.5.6]

to setup my environment I followed this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?package-manager=npm&platform=ios

When I do npm run ios, I am able to build app on simulator and device.
Then I followed this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device
to build App from xcode. then I get following error
Compile app_vers.c(arm64) 0.1 seconds
'Debug-iphoneos/AmplifyRTNCore/AmplifyRTNCore.modulemap' not found

I have tried following:

1. Deleting node_modules and re- running npm i > cd ios > bundle exec pod install > cd .. > npx pod-install.
2. Tried with rosetta [VSCode and terminal] couldn't do for xCode
3. Updated min_ios_version_supported to 11.0 and 13.0
4. tried Deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   And various other solutions available online

Answer (score 1):

My issue resolved, I was not starting react native server.

Answer (score 0):

- Could you check if your build problems are resolved by modifying your Podfile to delete the following lines?

  ```
  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
  config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"
  ```
- Change values in App Target > Build Settings > Architectures > Excluded Architectures to "arm64" it worked!

Screenshot for ref

[image]

Comment: config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = "arm64"

I dont have above lines in my pod file

I tried changing  Excluded Architectures to "arm64" and then I did pod update and still failing with same error.

Comment: You can modify the Xcode like I've indicated in the image, rather than changing the pod file. Then, clear the build folder and relaunch the application.

Comment: Yes I tried but result was same.